# pandas: how to select first or last by column in keep with drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As shown below, name must be keep in `fisrt` and team in `last`.

How can I accomplish this with `.drop_duplicates()` or otherwise?

```
   name  team ...
0  john  a    ...
1  mike  b    ...
2  john  c

↓

   name  team ...
0  john  c    ...
1  mike  b    ...
```

-- Additional note about comments --

`.groupby('name').agg({'team': 'last', 'country': 'first'})`

The way it works now, if the first line of `country` is `Nan`
If the first line of country is Nan, a value that is not the `first` will be obtained as follows.

Is this because the case of `Nan` is ignored?
Even if `first` is specified and `first` is `Nan`, `Nan` must still be retained.

```
   name  team  country ...
0  john   a    Nan     ...
1  mike  b     Brazil  ...
2  john  c     Canada  ...

↓

   name  team  country ...
0  john  c     Canada  ...
1  mike  b     Brazil  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.groupby()` function:

`df.groupby('name').agg({'team': 'last'})`.

Be aware that in the value that's returned per name is dependent on the sorting of your dataframe.

Comment: Is it impossible to keep the values in the original order?

Comment: You can restore the original order if you'd like by first getting an array of all unique values of the `name` column in the order they appear in the original dataframe: `names = df['name'].unique()`. Then use this array to change the order int he new dataframe with: `new_dataframe.loc[names, :]`

Comment: It's a little hard to explain, but is it also an ordering problem that the first value is included even though it is set to last?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but: the `.groupby().agg()` call returns the last value in the team column per name. So in you're case it selects the team `c` for `john`. The order of the `name` column is however not how it was before, that's why I added the other comment, so we end up with a dataframe that has the names in the original order and it selected the last appearing team for each name. If you want something else returned, let me know :-)

Comment: I have added details to the question.

Comment: By default the `first` and `last` functions in `pd.groupby.agg()` drop the `nan` values. If you want to keep them, you can replace `last` with `.iat(-1)` and `first` with `.iat(0)`. It will look something like: `df.groupby('name').agg({'team': lambda x: x.iat[-1], 'country': lambda x: x.iat[0]})`

Comment: This really helped! I was able to solve the problem. Thank you!